# Android Recyclerview, want to know how it determines the data list for listing

Tags: android, list, constructor, android-recyclerview

So I am trying to figure out how to use RecyclerView for listing items.
Unlike ListView which has an adapter that passes list to its constructor for the internal working, RecyclerView does not seem to have one,
for example, in a class extending RecyclerView.Adapter
We provide contructor to set list we declared.

`public CustomAdapter(Data[] myDataset) {
        this.mDataset = myDataset;
    }`

but how does RecyclerView.Adapter exactly know what to use?
for example, since the constructor is provided by us, it is possible that we make a contructor with put two parameters with two different data type lists/arrays.
Then how will the adapter know which list to use??

add: or does it use according to how you use your lists on onBingVIewHolder method? if so, then how does position parameter work?

Comment: in short : how does adapter wrap its dataset

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html) post. It has a very simple example with a pretty good overview/explanation of the recyclerview and how it works.

Comment: but it does not explain what I am asking. I want to know if it is possible to assign data from dataset1( ex array of string) to view1 and data from dataset2 (ex array of other data type) to view 2. Given that dataset1,2 are both in the same adapter class.

Comment: you can do that in `onBindViewHolder()` by seting data from two sources